# Package names in import statement are removed automatically in VSCODE for .go file . How to resolve this?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I start typing the code in .go file using VSCODE Editor as below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

as soon as the above is typed I save the file and then I find that I have lost the statement I have typed in import and the code remains as follows

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

though I am aware that the unused imports are automatically removed, I do not know how to resolve this. I need these packages for the remaining part of my source code and only with that understanding I have included these package names even when I began to write the code.

Which setting should I use to resolve this in VSCode Editor

Comment: "I do not know how to resolve this". There _is_ nothing to resolve. Your code as saved doesn't need net/http, it's thus removed. If you use net/http it won't be removed any longer.

Comment: Also note that unused imports are a compile-time error. If your IDE would not remove those, your app wouldn't compile and you couldn't run it.

Comment: Please understand that I have not completed my code completely and I need these packages in the course of writing code. But even before I complete the entire code when I save the source code .go file the IDE removes the package names and thus I have asked this question. My question was answered well by @Manjeet Thakur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> though I am aware that the unused imports are automatically removed, I
> do not know how to resolve this.

In vscode setting.json set this config

```
"[go]": {
     "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": false            
        }
}
```

Comment: This answer should also note that this will disable `organizeImports` completely, not just removing unused imports.